# Sending XHR request from cache resource

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching, offline

I am developing an offline website, when it opens for the first time  will be downloaded to cache memory. I have to check the internet connectivity on fixed interval of time.

The problem is when it will run on the server then it perfectly work for sending xhr request, but after downloading to the cache memory it will stop working.

```
    setInterval(function() { 
        var num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100000) + 1);    
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://example.com/offline/network.php?num="+num,
            type: "GET",
            data: {},
            error: function () {
                console.log('No intenet connection.');
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success : function (response) {
                saveToDb();
            }
        });
      }, 5*1000);
```

Comment: "offline website" with internet connectivity? how are you loading it? from a file:/// url? you can't do ajax requests in that case, as that'd be a cross-domain request.

Comment: Well, you'll need caching. Wrapping your AJAX class to add that is probably a good idea.

Comment: I have mentioned the code as well, please have a look.